# Transform dataset based on conditional addition - complicated

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform the following data from df1 to df2:

df1:

```
   ID  a  b  c  d  a-d  c-d  a-c-d
0   1  0  0  0  0    0    0      1
1   2  0  0  1  0    1    0      0
2   3  0  1  0  0    0    1      0
3   4  0  0  0  0    1    0      1
4   5  0  0  1  1    0    0      0
```

And df2 is:

```
   ID  a  b  c  d
0   1  1  0  1  1
1   2  1  0  1  1
2   3  0  1  1  1
3   4  2  0  1  2
4   5  0  0  1  1
```

Basically, I want to get the total values of "a", from all the columns in which the letter "a" appears in the column name. E.g. in the 4th row of df1 there are 2 column names in which the letter "a" appears. If you sum up all the "a" from the 4th row, there would be a total of 2 a's there. I want a single column for apples in the new dataset (df2). Note that a 1 for "a-c-d" is a 1 for EACH "a", "b", "c".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try `melt` to stack the column names, then `str.split` followed by `explode` to split the `a,b,c,d` and duplicate the data:

```
(df1.melt('ID', var_name='col')
    .assign(col=lambda x: x['col'].str.split('-'))
    .explode('col')
    .pivot_table(index='ID',columns='col', 
                 values='value', aggfunc='sum')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col  ID  a  b  c  d
0     1  1  0  1  1
1     2  1  0  1  1
2     3  0  1  1  1
3     4  2  0  1  2
4     5  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the unique categories in advance (e.g. ["a", "b", "c", "d"]) then you can take a little short cut and rely on `df.filter` to gather all of the columns with that letter, then use `.sum(axis=1)` to sum across those columns to create your expected summary value:

```
data = {"ID": df["ID"]}

for letter in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:
    data[letter] = df.filter(like=letter).sum(axis=1)
    
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(final_df)
   ID  a  b  c  d
0   1  1  0  1  1
1   2  1  0  1  1
2   3  0  1  1  1
3   4  2  0  1  2
4   5  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `split` then `explode` and `groupby` with `sum`

```
out = df.T.reset_index().assign(index=lambda x : x['index'].str.split('-')).explode('index').\
       groupby('index').sum().T
Out[102]: 
index  ID  a  b  c  d
0       1  1  0  1  1
1       2  1  0  1  1
2       3  0  1  1  1
3       4  2  0  1  2
4       5  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to complete the answers here, a method more manual is like follow:

```
df1.loc[:, 'a'] = df1.loc[:, 'a'] + df1.loc[:, 'a-d'] + df1.loc[:, 'a-c-d']  
df1.loc[:, 'c'] = df1.loc[:, 'c'] + df1.loc[:, 'c-d'] + df1.loc[:, 'a-c-d']
df1.loc[:, 'd'] = df1.loc[:, 'd'] + df1.loc[:, 'a-d'] + df1.loc[:, 'c-d'] + df1.loc[:, 'a-c-d']
```

Output:

```
col  ID  a  b  c  d
0     1  1  0  1  1
1     2  1  0  1  1
2     3  0  1  1  1
3     4  2  0  1  2
4     5  0  0  1  1
```